sklearn transformer for dropping features
I have a dataset with a large number of features, some of which I'd like to simply discard. I'd like to do this as part of a scikit-learn pipeline, whose first step drops the unwanted features. This requires an object which drops the features in a manner consistent with scikit-learn's transformer interface, implementing the fit and transform methods. I have written a class which does just this, but inserting the following code into a notebook is somewhat clunky. My question is, does some class already provided by scikit-learn provide the same functionality?
class Downsampler:
    """Downsamples input data according to the sklearn transform interface."""

    def __init__(self, keep):
        """
        keep should index the features *not* to be dropped. For instance, if only the middle two
        of four features are of interest, keep should be [1, 2] or [False, True, True, False].
        """
        self.keep_ = keep

    def fit(X, y=None):
        """Does nothing; provided for interface consistency."""
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        """Transform a data matrix of shape (n_samples, n_features) by dropping unwanted features."""
        return np.copy(X[:, self.keep_])

One use case, similar to my own, would be to downsample time series of a continuously changing quantity, to say, 1-minute resolution rather than 1-second. Another could be to ignore features which are known to be independent of a prediction target.

There is ColumnTransformer which you can use with FunctionTransformer (taking an identify function) or directly using the special-cased strings "drop" and "passthrough".
Example:
ColumnTransformer([("transformer_name", "drop", [columns_to_drop])], remainder="passthrough")


You don't need the FunctionTransformer: the strings "passthrough" and "drop" can be transformers in a ColumnTransformer.
